# Send data with POST in jQuery to PHP in the same file

Tags: php, mysql, email, post

I have mail.php file which contains two columns. One consists of a list of mails titles that I get with PHP from database (id of elements is set to mail id as it is in database). The other column should show message of the selected mail.

I have made a JS script which sets selected mail to active and gets its id attribute. Now I wan to send this id to PHP so that I can get message of the selected mail.

How can I use POST method to send id of selected item and get it with PHP in the same file?
Or if someone could explain me some better way to do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>...</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">
        <div class="list-group">
        <?php get emails and set element id=Mail_ID ?>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10">
      <div class="mail-text">
        <?php get id form JS script and show message ?>
       </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
<script>
  $('.list-group a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).closest('a').addClass('active');
    var active = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('id');

  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I didn't even have to use POST method to get the id of the email.
I managed to solve my problem like this:
1) First I saved mail text and id in the $messages array such that id is the key and message is the value. I did this in the div with class list-group when i fetch all data from database.
2) then in the script section I just changed the text in div with mail-text class like this

```
<script>
  $('.list-group a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).closest('a').addClass('active');
    var Mail_id = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('id');
    var mail_text=<?php echo json_encode($messages); ?>;
    var joined = mail_text[Mail_id];
    $('.message').text(joined);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Javascript

First you need to get the email id from somewhere (you should know from where) and put that in a variable. Then make an AJAX post request to a php file and do something with the returned data. This should get you started:

```
var Mail_id = //get the mail id from some field or something    
var formData = {id: Mail_id}; 

$.ajax({
    url : "/getMessageById.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

## PHP

Create a file called `getMessageById.php`

```
<?php
    $Mail_Id = json_decode($_POST["id"]);
    //dosomething with that id
?>
```

[more about JQUERY AJAX POST](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to send id in the same file? So that when I click on a mail only the div with mail-text class is updated and the list of mails stays the same?

Comment: Well because we're using AJAX post the page doesnt load or something. You could update the div with mail text class like so: `$('.mail-text').text(data);` ps: use that code inside your succes function of your AJAX POST call

Comment: No problem! Success with your mail app ;) ps: dont forget to close the answer by choosing the right answer haha